# DataSet designer opens as Xml editor

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xsd, dataset

I had a power outage and while I am certain I saved my work recently something did go wrong. The xsd file I was editing in the Designer mode no longer opens in designer, when I double click it, I get the xml of it. Strangely enough any other xsd I open opens perfectly as design-view. Resetting VS settings doesn't seem to help, can it be something in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way I could think of that would fix this problem, is to exclude that xsd(and its dependants) from the project, then in explorer delete all the files that have the same name as the xsd *but not the xsd itself*. Then add the xsd file back to project in Visual Studio and it will work fine again. The only downside is that it rearranges the visual aspect of the xsd :/

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

goto your Solutions Explorer.
right click the dataset you are trying to open up.
Click "Open With"
you should get a dialog box come up, select "Dataset Editor" and press ok.

From here on you should be all set again.

Steve

Comment: +1 This is what seems like the sane fix. The accepted answer worked, but this would have been more direct if I had seen it first.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Error window and see if you have any errors, warnings, or messages about the XML. Also look in the Output window to see if there are any complaints.

Comment: Surprisingly the whole project ran and compiled fine. I suspect the proj file may have gotten messed up.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I edit the .cs file under of .xsd file. Edit this file and erase all. that's it, works for me.